# How to catch error from iframe inside an Android webview

Tags: android, iframe, error-handling, android-webview

I use the below code to redirect users to an error page when my web based application receives error from server.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmls/error.html");
    }
});
```

But When an error occurs in iframes (not in the webpage itself), the error is not detected.

p.s.: I used fancybox for some operations and fancybox opens iframe in some cases.

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't find yet. We can catch script errors by interacting between frame and parent but I can't catch 500 or 404 etc. errors. @rraallvv

Comment: I've found a solution, but needs to be fully tested, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a JavascriptInterface to your webview?

```
JavaScriptInterface interface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "interface");

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface 
    public void doSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

And the Javascript side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function execute()
  {
    JSInterface.doSomething();
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="execute()" />
```

Comment: Do you mean I catch iframe errors by javascript and pass it to android?

Comment: So how can I set a global listener to any kind of errors using javascript?

Comment: Yes I mean to catch the error from your script, and then pass it to an Android JS method.  Maybe not the best solution but I really can't think anything els,e cause iframes tend to be a problem, especially with web views.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I was able to "catch" the error when the iframe fails to load, it intercepts all requests that start with `http://` or `https://`, and tries to do the request using `HttpURLConnection`, if some error is thrown it knows the request has failed. It hasn't been fully tested though.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    Boolean failedToLoad = false;

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (!failedToLoad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Page fully loaded");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        failedToLoad = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        failedToLoad = true;
    }

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!url.matches("^https?://.*$")) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            String mime;
            if (url.lastIndexOf('.') > url.lastIndexOf('/')) {
                String ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
            } else {
                mime = "text/html";
            }

            return new WebResourceResponse(mime, "UTF-8", conn.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            failedToLoad = true;
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```